# Rxjava2 + Retrofit2 + Android. Best way to do hundreds of network calls

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an app. I have a big button that allows the user to sync all their data at once to the cloud. A re-sync feature that allows them to send all their data again. (300+ entries)

I am using RXjava2 and retrofit2. I have my unit test working with a single call. However I need to make N network calls.

What I want to avoid is having the observable call the next item in a queue. I am at the point where I need to implement my runnable. I have seen a bit about Maps but I have not seen anyone use it as a queue. Also I want to avoid having one item fail and it report back as ALL items fail, like the Zip feature would do. Should I just do the nasty manager class that keeps track of a queue? Or is there a cleaner way to send several hundred items?

**NOTE: SOLUTION CANNOT DEPEND ON JAVA8 / LAMBDAS. That has proved to be way more work than is justified.**

Note all items are the same object.

```
    @Test
public void test_Upload() {
    TestSubscriber<Record> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    ClientSecureDataToolKit clientSecureDataToolKit = ClientSecureDataToolKit.getClientSecureDataKit();
    clientSecureDataToolKit.putUserDataToSDK(mPayloadSecureDataToolKit).subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
    testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
    testSubscriber.assertCompleted();
}
```

My helper to gather and send all my items

```
public class SecureDataToolKitHelper {
private final static String TAG = "SecureDataToolKitHelper";
private final static SimpleDateFormat timeStampSimpleDateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


public static void uploadAll(Context context, RuntimeExceptionDao<EventModel, UUID> eventDao) {
    List<EventModel> eventModels = eventDao.queryForAll();

    QueryBuilder<EventModel, UUID> eventsQuery = eventDao.queryBuilder();
    String[] columns = {...};

    eventsQuery.selectColumns(columns);

    try {
        List<EventModel> models;

        models = eventsQuery.orderBy("timeStamp", false).query();
        if (models == null || models.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<PayloadSecureDataToolKit> toSendList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (EventModel eventModel : models) {
            try {
                PayloadSecureDataToolKit payloadSecureDataToolKit = new PayloadSecureDataToolKit();

                if (eventModel != null) {


                  // map my items ... not shown

                    toSendList.add(payloadSecureDataToolKit);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error adding payload! " + e + " ..... Skipping entry");
            }
        }

        doAllNetworkCalls(toSendList);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

my Retrofit stuff

```
public class ClientSecureDataToolKit {

    private static ClientSecureDataToolKit mClientSecureDataToolKit;
    private static Retrofit mRetrofit;

    private ClientSecureDataToolKit(){
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Utilities.getSecureDataToolkitURL())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
    }

    public static ClientSecureDataToolKit getClientSecureDataKit(){
        if(mClientSecureDataToolKit == null){
            mClientSecureDataToolKit = new ClientSecureDataToolKit();
        }
        return mClientSecureDataToolKit;
    }

    public Observable<Record> putUserDataToSDK(PayloadSecureDataToolKit payloadSecureDataToolKit){
        InterfaceSecureDataToolKit interfaceSecureDataToolKit = mRetrofit.create(InterfaceSecureDataToolKit.class);
        Observable<Record> observable = interfaceSecureDataToolKit.putRecord(NetworkUtils.SECURE_DATA_TOOL_KIT_AUTH, payloadSecureDataToolKit);
        return observable;
    }

}

public interface InterfaceSecureDataToolKit {

@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})

@POST("/api/create")
Observable<Record> putRecord(@Query("api_token") String api_token, @Body PayloadSecureDataToolKit payloadSecureDataToolKit);
 }
```

---

Update. I have been trying to apply this answer to not much luck. I am running out of steam for tonight. I am trying to implement this as a unit test, like I did for the original call for one item.. It looks like something is not right with use of lambda maybe..

```
public class RxJavaBatchTest {
    Context context;
    final static List<EventModel> models = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        context = new MockContext();
        EventModel eventModel = new EventModel();
        //manually set all my eventmodel data here.. not shown 

        eventModel.setSampleId("SAMPLE0");
        models.add(eventModel);
        eventModel.setSampleId("SAMPLE1");
        models.add(eventModel);
        eventModel.setSampleId("SAMPLE3");
        models.add(eventModel);


    }

    @Test
    public void testSetupData() {
        Assert.assertEquals(3, models.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testBatchSDK_Upload() {


        Callable<List<EventModel> > callable = new Callable<List<EventModel> >() {

            @Override
            public List<EventModel> call() throws Exception {
                return models;
            }
        };

        Observable.fromCallable(callable)
                .flatMapIterable(models -> models)
                .flatMap(eventModel -> {
                    PayloadSecureDataToolKit payloadSecureDataToolKit = new PayloadSecureDataToolKit(eventModel);
                    return doNetworkCall(payloadSecureDataToolKit) // I assume this is just my normal network call.. I am getting incompatibility errors when I apply a testsubscriber...
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                }, true, 1);
    }

    private Observable<Record> doNetworkCall(PayloadSecureDataToolKit payloadSecureDataToolKit) {

        ClientSecureDataToolKit clientSecureDataToolKit = ClientSecureDataToolKit.getClientSecureDataKit();
        Observable observable = clientSecureDataToolKit.putUserDataToSDK(payloadSecureDataToolKit);//.subscribe((Observer<? super Record>) testSubscriber);
        return observable;
    }
```

Result is..

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_112-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compile<MyBuildFlavorhere>UnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

---

Edit. No longer trying Lambdas. Even after setting up the path on my mac, javahome to point to 1.8, etc. I could not get it to work. If this was a newer project I would push harder. However as this is an inherited android application written by web developers trying android, it is just not a great option. Nor is it worth the time sink to get it working. Already into the days of this assignment instead of the half day it should have taken.

I could not find a good non lambda flatmap example. I tried it myself and it was getting messy.

Comment: you don't need to subscribe to inner observable, because it's all one stream. see my edited answer, that's where you should subscribe. also take a look into this https://medium.com/@peter.tackage/overriding-rxandroid-schedulers-in-rxjava-2-5561b3d14212#.86w266e9r

Comment: `models` list in your test contains same object repeated three times. With sampleId equal to "SAMPLE3".

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that.. I am thinking my compiler is not liking the implementation of the first argument of flatmap. 
(Function<? super T, ? extends ObservableSource<? extends R>> mapper,

Comment: Simplified we are retuning   return clientSecureDataToolKit.putUserDataToSDK(payloadSecureDataToolKit).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); which putUserDataToSDK has a return type of Observable<Record>

Comment: make putUserDataToSDK return Observable<Record>

Comment: Aye that was in the last comment

Comment: The Lambda is what is screwing it up. I do not think this project will be able to run java8 + lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make your calls in parallel?

So rx-y way of doing this would be something like:

```
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> eventsQuery.orderBy("timeStamp", false).query())
            .flatMapIterable(models -> models)
            .flatMap(model -> {
                // map your model

                //avoid throwing exceptions in a chain, just return Observable.error(e) if you really need to
                //try to wrap your methods that throw exceptions in an Observable via Observable.fromCallable()


                return doNetworkCall(someParameter)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            }, true /*because you don't want to terminate a stream if error occurs*/, maxConcurrent /* specify number of concurrent calls, typically available processors + 1 */)
            .subscribe(result -> {/* handle result */}, error -> {/* handle error */});
```

In your `ClientSecureDataToolKit` move this part into constructor

```
    InterfaceSecureDataToolKit interfaceSecureDataToolKit = mRetrofit.create(InterfaceSecureDataToolKit.class);
```

Comment: I'll try it out later. But I just want to make the calls, parallel, serial, I just want the code to simple. How will the errors be handled?

Comment: You will handle them in your subscription.

Comment: Looking into this more. The Lambdas are an issue... As this is Java 7 land (android) but it is a great starting point.. But it is possible to do Java 8, however this inherited project would likely have issues.

Comment: Look into retrolambda. It is used by everyone on android.

Comment: If my code works, please accept the answer for future readers.

Comment: Sorry this java8 / lambda stuff is just not going to work. I appreciate the help but the solution needs to work with 1.7. (Which I did say 7 comments ago)

Comment: If you don't want to use retrolambda, use anonymous classes instead.